# SQL/Doctrine - Get first found row

Tags: sql, doctrine

can someone help me find the best solution for this:

Article table has `enabled: bool` column. Let's say table has 1M records.
I need to find a first row with `enabled` set to **true** and stop executing.

Why:
Trying to hide a category if the category doesn't have enabled articles.
So I need to check if at least one article is active.

*I'm using articles just for the sake of example.*

Thanks

PS: LIMIT 1 is just going through whole table and returns 1 row :( I need to stop executing after 1 row has been found.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which is right for you so here are the main two ways of doing this in SQL:

SQL Server style

```
select top 1 * from Article where enabled = 'True'
```

or Oracle style:

```
select * from Article where enabled = 'True' and rownum = 1
```